# My scene does not appear in Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

So, I tried to render a scene in eevee and there are the results
[image]

And here what's supposed to appear (*rendered in cycles*)[image]

I thought that reinstalling blender would help me in this situation, but it's still there. And when I was finishing writing the question, I decided to double-check the rendering.
 [image]
 And it works. I do not know how, but it works. ***It just works.***

Plz explain me, what's going on

Answer (score 2):

I found out that this problem appears when another program "Bandicam" is open. When it's in the game recording mode, it brokes the render results.